# Xamrin app on iOS giving trust failure error on new TLS certificate - AWS ELB

Tags: ssl-certificate, aws-application-load-balancer

I have a PHP app running behind AWS ALB. TLS tunnel terminates at the ALB and the traffic from ALB to the PHP servers (Apache) is over the self-signed cert TSL. Everything has been working great, no issue. Now our certificate is about to expire, so I renewed the cert from Godaddy, uploaded it to ALB. My website works well with the new cert. I have a react native app that works well too. However, my Xamrin app throws a "Trust Failure" error. It looks like Xamrin is keeping the old certificate and not using the new one. Any help appreciated.

Edit

I commented out the code for certificate pinning but I still got the trust failure. So I got the new cert and pinned that cert. Now the app is working. I wish I could just not pin the cert. Well, I am running against the time, cert expiring next day, so I am going to go with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the issue. The developers had pinned the public certificate in the Xamrin app. We removed the pinning, still, the app was throwing a trust failure error. So we simply pinned the app to the new cert and released app. Not the ideal solution for us, I wanted to not pin the cert. But had no time to debug, we were running out of time as the cert was about the expire.